# How to I see if an EditText has a date input type programmatically?

Tags: java, android, validation

I'm trying to validate an EditText on save. I have the following code:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/iconValue"
    android:id="@+id/birthDateEditText"
    android:hint="Birth Date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:inputType="date" />
```

I use the getInputType() property to check the type:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) view;
int type = editText.getInputType();

if (type == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME) {
    if (editText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && isValidDateControl(editText)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I have tried a large number of InputType values but the second if statement is never hit when stepping through. The variable `type` is returning 20 for its value. I could check to see if the type is 20, but would prefer not to do this.

Comment: Simple if you could System.out.print(type); my guess is it might not be coming as '4'.

Comment: You are right--it's printing 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE` is what is equal to `android:inputType`.
Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).
This means your code should work when changing the if-clause to:

```
if (type == (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE))
```

Comment: SUPER @MALAKA, thanks for reference also. I am searching for 2 hours and your answer helped me a lot.